# Как для DependencyProperty задать конвертер?

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

У моего элемента управления есть некоторая величина, типа `double`. Как мне сделать так, чтобы ее можно было задавать как `auto` или вообще в процентах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы программно установить ширину "Auto", нужно использовать значение Double.NaN:

```
myControl.Width = Double.NaN;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Именно то, что нужно.